# Modificar valor de objeto

Tags: javascript

En el siguiente código se crean objetos libros y se guardan en el array libros una vez creados si se decidiera prestar un libro pondríamos el nombre del libro a prestar y pulsaríamos asignar préstamo y el valor de préstamo tendría que cambiar a 'true'.

El problema que tengo es que la parte de asignar préstamo no me funciona ya que al hacerlo el valor sigue en false.

```js
function Libro(nombre, prestado) {
    
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.prestado = prestado;
}

// Prestado false por defecto.
Libro.prestado = false;

var libros = [];

function obtenerNombre() {
  
  var obtenerN = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  return obtenerN;
  
}

function crearLibro() {
  
  var nuevoLibro = new Libro(obtenerNombre(), Libro.prestado);
  libros.push(nuevoLibro);
  mostrarListado();
}

function mostrarListado(){
  var lista='';
  for(var i=0; i<libros.length; i++){
    lista+= 
      '\n Nombre : ' + libros[i].nombre + '\n' +
      ' Prestado : ' + libros[i].prestado + '\n' ;
  }
  document.getElementById('listado').innerText = lista;
}

function asignarPrestamo(){

  var nombre2 = (document.getElementById('nombre2').value);
    for (var i=0; i<libros.length; i++){
      if (libros[i].nombre===nombre2){
        this.prestado = true;
      }
    }
    mostrarListado();
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Actividad 2. disco</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="libro.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" placeHolder="Nombre de libro"/>
                <input type="button" onClick="crearLibro();" value="Enviar mis datos!"/>
            </form>

            <form>
                <input type="text" id="nombre2" placeHolder="Nombre de libro" />
                <input type="button" onClick="asignarPrestamo();" value="Asignar prestamo" />
            </form>

            <div id="listado"></div>
        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la función asignarPrestamo tienes un error:

```
function asignarPrestamo(){

  var nombre2 = (document.getElementById('nombre2').value);
  for (var i=0; i<libros.length; i++){
    if (libros[i].nombre===nombre2){
      this.prestado = true; // <-- this no es el libro
    }
  }
  mostrarListado();
}
```

Una vez corriges ese error, sustituyendo `this` por `libros[i]`, todo funciona

```js
function Libro(nombre, prestado) {
    
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.prestado = prestado;
}

// Prestado false por defecto.
Libro.prestado = false;

var libros = [];

function obtenerNombre() {
  
  var obtenerN = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  return obtenerN;
  
}

function crearLibro() {
  
  var nuevoLibro = new Libro(obtenerNombre(), Libro.prestado);
  libros.push(nuevoLibro);
  mostrarListado();
}

function mostrarListado(){
  var lista='';
  for(var i=0; i<libros.length; i++){
    lista+= 
      '\n Nombre : ' + libros[i].nombre + '\n' +
      ' Prestado : ' + libros[i].prestado + '\n' ;
  }
  document.getElementById('listado').innerText = lista;
}

function asignarPrestamo(){

  var nombre2 = (document.getElementById('nombre2').value);
    for (var i=0; i<libros.length; i++){
      if (libros[i].nombre===nombre2){
        libros[i].prestado = true;
      }
    }
    mostrarListado();
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Actividad 2. disco</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="libro.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" placeHolder="Nombre de libro"/>
                <input type="button" onClick="crearLibro();" value="Enviar mis datos!"/>
            </form>

            <form>
                <input type="text" id="nombre2" placeHolder="Nombre de libro" />
                <input type="button" onClick="asignarPrestamo();" value="Asignar prestamo" />
            </form>

            <div id="listado"></div>
        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```